# Objective-C runtime method_exchangeImplementations is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Below is my code, please help me to find what is the reason of this error.
error is

> xxx_objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index is not working

Code:

```
+ (void)load 
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    Class class = [self class];
    /* When swizzling a class method, use the following: */
    /* Class class = object_getClass((id)self); */

    SEL originalSelector = @selector(objectAtIndex:);/* NSArray's way */
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(xxx_objectAtIndex:);/* will change way */

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);


  });
}
/*but when I use objectAtIndex: not perform this way*/
- (id)xxx_objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

   NSLog(@"=========1===========");
   if (index < self.count)
   {
       return [self xxx_objectAtIndex:index];
   }

   return @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given from NSHipster [article](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) I think you should do it in this way.

```
       BOOL didAddMethod =
            class_addMethod(class,
                originalSelector,
                method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                swizzledSelector,
                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
```

Comment: when i use your ways, always can't perform this way xxx_objectAtIndex:

Comment: in class_getInstanceMethod method you used class. Try using self.

Comment: I use this way at UIViewController exchange viewWillAppear and success,but use this way at NSArray failure

Comment: Which class are you doing this in?

Comment: UIViewController and NSArray

Comment: Did you try write a category to NSArray?